# Android does not need to enable debuggable to run dumpheap

Tags: android, adb

Running am dumpheap with root privileges still fails because debuggable is not enabled.
​I don't mind if root is required,app runs on Android emulator x86

" am dumpheap "

nox Night God Simulator
夜神模拟器,凑字数，凑字数，凑字数。。